# Trigger an event based only on user inactivity

Tags: windows-10, hibernate, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, idle

Windows 10 Task Scheduler can trigger an event after certain time of idle status,
where the 'idle' is defined by user keyboard mouse input and other conditions such as CPU usage.

Can I define a condition solely based on 'no keyboard or mouse input?'
Since CPU usage may not be completed controlled by myself if some jobs are running.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your goal cannot be achieved.

In Windows, the Task Scheduler verifies that the computer is in an idle state every 15 minutes. Task Scheduler checks for an idle state using two criteria: user absence, and a lack of resource consumption. The user is considered absent if there is no keyboard or mouse input during this period of time. The computer is considered idle if all the processors and all the disks were idle for more than 90% of the last detection interval.

Task Scheduler considers a processor as idle even when low priority threads (thread priority < normal) execute.